# jquery ajax load with delay - php div rotation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, delay

Hope someone can help.  I am new to javascript so please forgive any mistakes.  I am trying to achieve the following:

I have an index page with an html table, split up into four quarters.  Each quarter has a DIV ID, and an ajax load via jquery will reload individual DIV's with a PHP page sucessfully, after a certain delay.

What I am trying to do, is for one of the quarters, rotate three PHP pages in the DIV every 15 minutes, and keep looping.  I had setup an array with three php sites in, and sucessfully used this with a counter variable to call the relavent entries in the array via jquery. If I put in the count number in the ajax code it works.  I am now struggling to see how I can increment the counter, and also reset it once it has reached the third page.

I do not know if I can use the ajax.complete function to assist, as I dont know if I can put "standard" javascript inside this function.

Thanks for any assistance - my code is below:

```
var count = 0;
var page = new Array("page1.php","page2.php","page3.php");
var delay = ("9000");


    (
function($)
{
$(document).ready(function()  
{        
$.ajaxSetup(        
    {            
        cache: false


    });  
    var $container = $("#DivID"); 
    $container.load(page[count]);    
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()  
    {           
        $container.load(page[count]); 
    }, delay); 



});

})

(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()  
{           
    $container.load(page[count]);
    count = (count+1) % 3 
}, delay);
```

This way when count reaches 3 it will be reset to 0. Percent sign is the module division

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Set Interval.

it will lag and chain if the page load is slow, crashing your site

use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function_name, delay);

var function_name = function() {
    $container.load(page[count], function(){
        count = (count+1) % 3;
        setTimeout(function_name, delay);
    });


}
```

this way, the timeout isn't chained, it fires once the page load is completed